# How to prevent menu from moving on FAB hide?

Tags: android, layout, menu, floating-action-button

I have `BottomAppBar` with `FloatingActionButton`. When I use `fab.hide()` menu shifted from right corner to left. How fix this?

How it's looks:

[image]

Then I click:

[image]

Comment: other than calling `fab.hide();` try instead `fab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`

Comment: @MohammedAlaa if change visibility, empty space under FAB remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove menu attribute and add icons like this:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:fabAlignmentMode="end">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_more" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_search" />

</com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>
```

After removing menu attribute you have to create overflow menu yourself, if you need one.